# Wordpress: jQuery/JavaScript in plugin only works when logged in

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

What code exactly do I need to incorporate into my plugin to make it function both when logged in, and logged out?

```
function getdetailedsearchresults_scripts() {
    global $post;
    $temp = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

    if (in_array($post->post_name, array('detailed-search-results', 'detailed-gym-gw', 'detailed-gyms-page')) || in_array($temp, array('192.0.0.50')) ){
        wp_enqueue_script(
            'getdetailedsearchresults-script',
            plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . "assets/getdetailedsearchresults.js",
            array('jquery'),
            '1.0',
            true
        );
    }
    wp_localize_script(
        'getdetailedsearchresults-script', // this needs to match the name of our enqueued script
        'resultsSearchDetailed',      // the name of the object
        array('ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')) // the property/value
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'getdetailedsearchresults_scripts' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_detailedsearchresults', 'detailedsearchresults_callback' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_no_priv_detailedsearchresults', 'detailedsearchresults_callback' );
function detailedsearchresults_callback() { }
```

Comment: Isn't is possible to use the wp function? https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/

Comment: Im getting a `Fatal error: Call to undefined function is_user_logged_in()` message when doing `if ( is_user_logged_in() ){}`